# Timer not working correctly

Tags: qt, animation, timer, qml, qt-quick

We have to make progress bar consisting with slider, which has colour transition as the slider proceeds as shown in the figure below.

[image: Progress Bar]

I tried my hand with below logic but could not get the desired effect. Any help or suggestion how to implement the same.

Below is my code snippet

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: container

    width: 500; height: 400

    Row {
        id:repeaterid
        x: 75
        y: 280
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 114
        spacing: 4
        Repeater {
            model: 50
            Rectangle {
                id: smallrect
                color: "red"
                width:4
                height:4
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: progressTimer
        interval: 50
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            if (slider.x < 460)
            {
                slider.x += repeaterid.spacing + 4
                smallrect.color = "green"
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: slider
        x: repeaterid.x
        y: repeaterid.y
        width: 6; height: 6
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

I have tried to use ColorAnimation, but got any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the items within the repeater you can use the **itemAt(index)** function. This will allow you to change the color of the repeaters children. I also added a **indexCurrent** property to keep track of the current index.

Try this code:

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle {
  id: container

  width: 500; height: 400

  property int indexCurrent: 0

  Row {
    id:repeaterid
    x: 75
    y: 280
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    anchors.bottomMargin: 114
    spacing: 4
    Repeater {
        id: repeater
        model: 50
        Rectangle {
            id: smallrect
            color: "red"
            width:4
            height:4
        }
    }
  }

  Timer {
    id: progressTimer
    interval: 50
    running: true
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        if (slider.x < 460)
        {
            slider.x += repeaterid.spacing + 4
            repeater.itemAt(indexCurrent).color = "green"
            indexCurrent = indexCurrent + 1
        }
    }
  }

  Rectangle {
    id: slider
    x: repeaterid.x
    y: repeaterid.y
    width: 6; height: 6
    color: "blue"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The timer works correctly. The problem is entirely different: Your try to access `smallrect` in the `onTriggerd` handler, an undefined reference outside of the `Repeater`. Try to solve the problem more declarative:

- use an integer property in the `container` to store the current position of progress bar
- in `smallrect` use the value of that property to set the color (`index < position? "green":` ... )
- use a `Timer` or better a `NumberAnimation` to update that property
- get rid of `slider` rectangle, just give the right rectangle in the `Repeater` a blue color

Comment: Thanks Sebasgo for your suggestion, will definitely implement them.